# ¿Cómo resolver un fallo al validar tipos mime para carga de imágenes en Zendframework 3x?

Tags: php, zend

Estoy desarrollando un módulo de extensión para Zendframework 3x (cuyos detalles no son importantes para el tema.) Este debe contar con un utilitario para carga de imágenes desde el cliente, de modo que las validaciones son muy importantes, particularmente por los ataques por suplantación de tipos y por incrustación de código malicioso en ciertos tipos de imágenes como `.gif` que hacen posible incluir bloques ejecutables dentro de comentarios).

Para resolver el asunto extendí la clase ***IsImage*** de ZF3 que ofrece un conjunto de validadores que parecen adecuados y prometen ahorrar mucho trabajo. Grosso modo:

```
class ImageMimeGeter extends IsImage {
    protected $tipoencontrado = '';

    public function isValid($value, $file = null) {
        $done = parent::isValid($value, $file);
        $this->tipoencontrado = ($done) ? $this->type : '';
        return $done;
    }

    public function tipoMime(){
        return $this->tipoencontrado;
    }
    // sigue código no pertinente para la consulta
}
```

Al construir instancias de esta clase para validar los tipos de los archivos de imagen que subo al servidor de desarrollo el proceso aborta y devuelve la típica página en blanco de ZF3 que revela un fallo grave. (Literalmente el "sistema se cae").

Estuve haciendo validaciones revisando paso a paso los métodos que ejecutan la clase madre que extendí y las que aquella extiende y logré identificar el momento (llamado) que aborta el proceso de validación:

```
/* recojo la información de archivo en $_FILES y la formateo 
   correctamente para poderla pasar a los validadores 
   el método recogerImagenACargar() no existe lo supongoo para
   ilustrar la situación. (el mecanismo de formateo es complejo porque
   $_FILES es un array con varios formatos posibles que dependen de que 
   la carga sea individual o múltiple y de si hay uno o varios elementos
   input de tipo file) */
$imagen_a_subir = recogerImagenACargar($_FILES);
$validador = new ImageMimeGeter();
$esvalida = $validador->isValid($imagen_a_subir);
/* En este punto me podrían decir que no estoy respetando la signatura 
   del método isValid() pero no es cierto, acepta que le sea pasado el
   array de información del archivo a subir como único parámetro */

// El método de validación delega en parent la tarea, invocando:
$done = parent::isValid($value, $file);

/* Entré a revisar el código de ZF3 y me encontré con que el proceso 
   avanza sin fallos hasta el momento marcado abajo (copio parcialmente
   los métodos de ZF3 involucrados ya que cabe esperar que quien brinde 
   ayuda conoce el framework) */
/**
 * NOTA: Este método se encuentra en la clase MimeType
 *
 * Defined by Zend\Validator\ValidatorInterface
 *
 * Returns true if the mimetype of the file matches the given ones. Also parts
 * of mimetypes can be checked. If you give for example "image" all image
 * mime types will be accepted like "image/gif", "image/jpeg" and so on.
 *
 * @param  string|array $value Real file to check for mimetype
 * @param  array        $file  File data from \Zend\File\Transfer\Transfer (optional)
 * @return bool
 */
public function isValid($value, $file = null)
{
    if (is_string($value) && is_array($file)) {
        // Legacy Zend\Transfer API support
        $filename = $file['name'];
        $filetype = $file['type'];
        $file     = $file['tmp_name'];
    } elseif (is_array($value)) {
        if (!isset($value['tmp_name']) || !isset($value['name']) || !isset($value['type'])) {
            throw new Exception\InvalidArgumentException(
                'Value array must be in $_FILES format'
            );
        }
        $file     = $value['tmp_name'];
        $filename = $value['name'];
        $filetype = $value['type'];
    } else {
        $file     = $value;
        $filename = basename($file);
        $filetype = null;
    }
    $this->setValue($filename);

    // Is file readable ?
    if (empty($file) || false === stream_resolve_include_path($file)) {
        $this->error(static::NOT_READABLE);
        return false;
    }

    // AQUÍ Aborta el proceso. Falla al ejecutar getMagicFile()
    $mimefile = $this->getMagicFile();
    // Dejo el resto del método porque ilustra un excelente tratamiento
    // de la validación de tipos mime (Razón por la que me gusta ZFx)
    if (class_exists('finfo', false)) {
        if (!$this->isMagicFileDisabled() && (!empty($mimefile) && empty($this->finfo))) {
            ErrorHandler::start(E_NOTICE|E_WARNING);
            $this->finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE, $mimefile);
            ErrorHandler::stop();
        }

        if (empty($this->finfo)) {
            ErrorHandler::start(E_NOTICE|E_WARNING);
            $this->finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
            ErrorHandler::stop();
        }

        $this->type = null;
        if (!empty($this->finfo)) {
            $this->type = finfo_file($this->finfo, $file);
        }
    }

    if (empty($this->type) && $this->getHeaderCheck()) {
        $this->type = $filetype;
    }

    if (empty($this->type)) {
        $this->error(static::NOT_DETECTED);
        return false;
    }

    $mimetype = $this->getMimeType(true);
    if (in_array($this->type, $mimetype)) {
        return true;
    }

    $types = explode('/', $this->type);
    $types = array_merge($types, explode('-', $this->type));
    $types = array_merge($types, explode(';', $this->type));
    foreach ($mimetype as $mime) {
        if (in_array($mime, $types)) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    $this->error(static::FALSE_TYPE);
    return false;
}
```

Luego de identificar que el proceso avanza sin problemas hasta el punto señalado arriba `getMagicFile()` entré a revisar dicho procedimiento paso a paso e identifiqué el posible germen del mal:

```
/**
 * Returns the actual set magicfile
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getMagicFile()
{
    if (null === $this->options['magicFile']) {
        $magic = getenv('magic');
        if (!empty($magic)) {
            // Si hubiese pasado por acá se habría caído como ocurre más
            // abajo
            $this->setMagicFile($magic);
            if ($this->options['magicFile'] === null) {
                $this->options['magicFile'] = false;
            }
            return $this->options['magicFile'];
        }

        foreach ($this->magicFiles as $file) {
            try {
            // En este punto se cae a pesar del try que se presume
            // atrapa el error y permite seguir
                $this->setMagicFile($file);
            } catch (Exception\ExceptionInterface $e) {
                // suppressing errors which are thrown due to open_basedir restrictions
                continue;
            }

            if ($this->options['magicFile'] !== null) {
                return $this->options['magicFile'];
            }
        }

        if ($this->options['magicFile'] === null) {
            $this->options['magicFile'] = false;
        }
    }

    return $this->options['magicFile'];
}
```

Antes de tratar de revisar qué pasa con el método `setMagicFile($file)`, revisé el array de archivos mágicos recogidos por `getenv()` y sus paths para descartar problemas de privilegios de acceso. obtuve la siguiente lista:

```
    /usr/share/misc/magic
    /usr/share/misc/magic.mime
    /usr/share/misc/magic.mgc
    /usr/share/mime/magic
    /usr/share/mime/magic.mime
    /usr/share/mime/magic.mgc
    /usr/share/file/magic
    /usr/share/file/magic.mime
    /usr/share/file/magic.mgc
```

que como se puede observar están en directorios compartidos a los que el aplicativo tiene acceso.
Pasé, entonces a revisar el método `setMagicFile($file)` y me encontré que camina hasta invocar un método intrínseco de php: `finfo_open()`

Pase a consultar la documentación oficial de php (manual en español) y encontré un warning desagradable (que motiva esta farragosa consulta):

> Advertencia
>   El formato esperado de la base de datos mágica cambió en PHP 5.3.11 y 5.4.1. Debido a esto, la base de datos mágica interna ha sido actualizada. Esto mayormente efectua código donde se use una base de datos mágica externa: leer un fichero mágico antiguo ahora fallará. Además, algunas representaciones textuales de los tipos mime han cambiado, por ejemplo, para PHP sería devuelto "PHP script, ASCII text" en lugar de "PHP script text".

El servidor que empleo para desarrollo tiene instalado Php 5.6 y el sistema es Ubuntu 18.04 que a su vez tiene instalado Php 7.2 De modo que me lleva a pensar que muy seguramente los fallos detectados provienen del uso del método `finfo_open()`.

Hice una prueba aparte de funcionamiento del método en cuestión  pasando uno a uno los elementos del array mime (anotado arriba) para tratar de provocar el fallo y me encontré que no derriba el sistema en ningún caso, aunque falla en la mayoría, usé el siguiente código:

```
<?php
    $mimefiles = [
        '/usr/share/misc/magic',
        '/usr/share/misc/magic.mime',
        '/usr/share/misc/magic.mgc',
        '/usr/share/mime/magic',
        '/usr/share/mime/magic.mime',
        '/usr/share/mime/magic.mgc',
        '/usr/share/file/magic',
        '/usr/share/file/magic.mime',
        '/usr/share/file/magic.mgc'
    ];
    foreach ($mimefiles as $mf) {
        $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE, $mf);
        if($finfo){
            mdf('Abierto '.$mf, 'warning');
        }else{
            mdf('FALLO al Abrir '.$mf, 'warning');
        }
        finfo_close($finfo);
    }
// mdf() es una función de mi API personal que me ofrece mensajes de
// depuración con formato (similar a un Dump pero con formato amigable)
```

y obtuve la siguiente salida:

```
Abierto /usr/share/misc/magic
FALLO al Abrir /usr/share/misc/magic.mime
FALLO al Abrir /usr/share/misc/magic.mgc
FALLO al Abrir /usr/share/mime/magic
FALLO al Abrir /usr/share/mime/magic.mime
FALLO al Abrir /usr/share/mime/magic.mgc
Abierto /usr/share/file/magic
FALLO al Abrir /usr/share/file/magic.mime
FALLO al Abrir /usr/share/file/magic.mgc
```

De modo que la hipótesis del fallo del método es falsa. En consecuencia, me encuentro en una encrucijada que me obliga a solicitar sugerencias. Si usted soportó todo el cuento, le estoy muy agradecido, si además puede ofrecerme una sugerencia razonable, tendré con usted una deuda inmensa. Gracias por "escucharme" leer.

Comment: Yo me dejaría de versiones viejunas de PHP. Si estas desarrollando algo que sea para php7.x Los que aún tengan versiones anteriores pues tienen un problema y deberían actualizarse sin demora.

Comment: es necesario mantener la imagen original? una forma de sanitizar imagenes es redimensionarlas, podes extraer la data exif en otro proceso para reinsertarlo si hace falta

Comment: @aloMalbarez Gracias por la sugerencia. Pero, leí (no recuerdo en qué consulta en StackOverflow Security) que en algunos casos al redimensionar la imagen hay riesgo de ejecutar, código malicioso que se haya insertado en ellas. Mi propósito de fondo es rechazar cualquier imagen que pueda ser dudosa, sin caer en posturas paranoides que lleven a bloquear lo que viene bien. En cuanto a la posibilidad de "repintar la imagen" en el servidor es buena, pero no resuelve la validación de tipo mime, que es caso particular de una necesidad más general.

Comment: y llamando directamente a `ImageMagick` ? aquí hay algo parecido de errores en mimetypes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33276634/1423096

Comment: Si esa respuesta ya la había visto, está en mis referencias de consulta. Pero, en otras consultas encotré que no era sano pues `ImageMagic` tiene alrededor de 10 vulneralilidades (no recuerdo la cifra exacta).

Comment: tal vez sea demasiado extremo pero.. y un sandboxing usando containers? https://hub.docker.com/r/v4tech/imagemagick/

Comment: @aloMalbarez Buen enlace! no lo conocía. Voy a probarlo para "tareas de mantenimiento" de los directorios de imágenes. Parece que permite uniformar lo que ya ha sido aceptado (aunque en borrador tengo otro plan para esa tarea). No veo claro su uso sin aceptar previamente las imágenes pues mientras se están validando siguen en `/tmp/` y usarlo allí supondría hacer skip de `move_uploaded_file()`

Comment: en situaciones normales, con aceptarlo y moverlo a una carpeta no accesible desde fuera no habría problemas de código malicioso ejecutándose, de hecho puede incluso haber un antivirus y/o antimalware monitoreando esa carpeta con la orden de borrar. si sube lo moves y luego no existe algo pasó, luego la sanitización/validación del mimetype puede ser delegada y sandboxeada registrando un callback como parte del proceso de subida (como cuando adjuntas un ejecutable o archivo comprimido al componer un mail de gmail)

Comment: @aloMalbarez me gusta esta idea de solución para validar. Me queda una inquietud: Estoy (estaba) tratando de extender un objeto de [tag:zendframework] al seguir este curso de acción abandono el uso de los validadores que aquel ofrece y me paso a "php puro" que no es grave, pero hace un poco menos estructural la solución. Y, queda el sinsabor de ignorar la razón por la que usar la clase derriba la página.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79774/discussion-between-quevedo-and-alo-malbarez).